# How do you update a minor mode definition as you develop it?

Tags: minor-mode

I started coding a minor mode to provide some keybindings. My initial attempt had a typo:

```el
(define-minor-mode borked-mode
  "A mode defined with a broken key binding"
  nil nil
  '(([b] . 'previous-line)))
```

I had intended to use the `b` key, and immediately realized that I should have used `"b"` instead of `[b]`. So I redefined the minor mode:

```el
(define-minor-mode borked-mode
  "A mode defined with a broken key binding"
  nil nil
  '(("b" . 'previous-line)))
```

However, this didn't work. This set me off on a wild goose chase through all the various ways of binding keys (i.e., (kbd ...), [ ... ], etc). Finally I realized that simply re-evaluating the `(define-minor-mode ...)` form was not changing anything, I was stuck with the original, broken key map. I then tried changing the keymap directly via `(define-key borked-mode-map ...)` and still couldn't get the corrected keymap loaded. Finally I restarted Emacs, and my minor mode was correctly loaded.

**My question is:** how do you update a minor mode definition as you develop it? Is there any way to flush a broken definition, or do you have to restart emacs to clear away broken bits?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first time you evaluate your `define-minor-mode` it defines a variable `borked-mode-map` with the key bindings you specified. Once that symbol has been defined, however, re-evaluating your `define-minor-mode` won't change it.

You could delete the various `borked-mode-xxx` symbols using `unintern` and then re-evaluate your code. Try:

```
(unintern 'borked-mode-map)
```

You might be interested in expanding the `define-minor-mode` macro to see what it is actually doing. Put point at the end and call `M-x pp-macroexpand-last-sexp`. This will open a new buffer showing the expanded macro. There you'll see the `defvar` calls used to set up your mode variables. If you read the help for `defvar` you'll see that the initial value is only used if the symbol being defined is void -- once it exists, subsequent `defvar` calls won't change its value.

Answer (score 15):

I think the best answer I can give you is to stay away from the "inline keybindings feature" of `define-minor-mode`.  Use

```
(defvar borked-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [b] 'previous-line)
    ...
    map))

(define-minor-mode borked-mode
  "A mode defined with a broken key binding"
  :global nil
  ...)
```

Instead.  Then you can use `C-M-x` to re-evaluate those definitions.

Comment: `defvar` won't evaluate it's value again after `C-M-x` :) You'd need `defparameter` or a separate `setf`.

Comment: As @wvxvw points out, this does not actually address the issue. Your example code is doing the same that the `define-minor-mode` macro does: calling `defvar` to define the map. Evaluating that defvar a second time has no effect.

Comment: @wvxvw If you use `C-M-x` (`eval-defun`) to reevaluate the `defvar` then the variable is updated. This is a special case in `eval-defun`; if you call `eval-buffer` or `eval-region` then the existing value isn't changed.

Comment: Ah -- that seems like the key point.

Comment: @Gilles the more you learn... I had no idea `eval-defun` is any different in this respect. Good to know though.

Comment: Note that `C-M-x` on the `defvar` form only updates the mode-map variable itself. You have to also `C-M-x` on the `define-minor-mode` form to get the changed map 'installed' into the minor mode. I tried to figure out why by expanding the macros, but it's beyond me.

Comment: @Tyler The reason is that the `define-minor-mode` macro causes the *value* of the keymap's symbol (rather than the symbol itself) to be added to `minor-mode-map-alist` (via the generated call to `add-minor-mode`).  Therefore subsequently setting the keymap symbol to some other value does not affect the one in the alist.

Comment: thanks @phils that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can define your mode map like this:

```
(defvar dnd-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (prog1 map
      (define-key map "q" 'dnd-quit)
      (when (eq this-command 'eval-defun)
        (let ((mmap (assq 'dnd-mode minor-mode-map-alist)))
          (when mmap
            (setcdr mmap map)))))))
```

Now you are able to reevaluate the map definition using `eval-defun` and it will automatically update the stored map inside `minor-mode-map-alist`.